# How to manage notifications for events to individual members rather than whole team?

Tags: azure-devops

One of our managers who is on the team for the project asked how to avoid getting so many emails.  Basically, its just myself and another dev that really care anything about getting the email notifications when "something happens".  Can I change the default notifications to use just individual email addresses, or do I need to make a new "subscription" in the project settings and then where do I use individual email addresses?

Comment: Are you a collection or project admin?

Comment: I am a project admin

Comment: Probably will need to disable the global notifications, then go through the configuration defined @ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/notifications/concepts-email-recipients?view=azure-devops

Comment: @bitshift Not get your latest information, is the answer helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I change the default notifications to use just individual email
> addresses

The default subscriptions cannot be modified, as Matt pointed out in the comment, you can choose to disable default subscriptions, then new subscription, set delivery to individual email addresses. The email gets sent to multiple custom email addresses, which are separated by semicolons.

[image]

But a more convenient way is to set **Delivery settings**.

> Deliver to email address: notifications are delivered to a specific
> email address.

[image]